# C# - WPF/WP Binding from database - proper way? MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

Let's say that I have this class as a **Model** (database generated from it):

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

In **ViewModel**, I have an ObservableCollection Customers that holds all the customers from the database:

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers;
```

"Customers" are populated from the database.

In a **View**, ListBox is populated from Customers:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
```

Here is the problem. Let's say I want to insert a new customer into a database, what approach should I take in order to track the changes via UI:

**Resetting the ItemsSource: (Currently using this - worst approach)**

```
ListBoxExample.ItemsSource = null;
ListBoxExample.ItemsSource = Customers;
```

**Tracking changes via ObservableCollection Customers**

For example, if I want to insert something into database, insert it into Customers too and UI will be notified about the change.

**What are the other options?**

What is the best MVVM approach to achieve the following:

- Parse JSON data and insert it into local database
- Retrieve data from the local database and populate ListBox/ListView with it
- If new data is inserted into database or item is deleted/changed, update changes in ListBox/ListView

If I want to add item in database, I can simply add item to Customers list and add it to database. However, let's say that I delete an object from database, observable collection "Customers" won't be notified of that and will be out of sync (UI also won't update). Is there a way to dig deeper into MVVM structure and instead of adding/removing/changing items in observable collection AND database, to somehow make observable collection track the changes in database (if change is done via other application for example).

Comment: I think you may have some issues with your understanding of how to populate a ListBox with Items in an MVVM project. This should be done with binding, not by directly referencing the ListBox in your ViewModel. If your collection is Customers, your ListBox declaration should look like: <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Customers} /> . Then you use Add/Remove/Clear methods on your collection to manage its content.

Comment: If you add items, add them to the observable collection.  If you remove them, remove them from the collection. Do this via a binding in xaml rather than codebehind.  If you're not using bindings you're doing MVVM in WPF wrong.  `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"`

Comment: Updated thread to prevent confusion. I don't think you got my question. If I want to add item in database, I can simply add item to Customers list and add it to database. However, let's say that I delete an object from database, observable collection "Customers" won't be notified of that and will be out of sync (UI also won't update). Is there a way to dig deeper into MVVM structure and instead of adding/removing/changing items in observable collection AND database, to somehow make observable collection track the changes in database (if change is done via other application for example).

Comment: @Millkovac Did you find any best practices?

Comment: I am not really satisfied with the solution I found but here is what I've changed. In ViewModel I have an ObservableCollection that gets loaded with items from Database when application runs. Then, I use binding to set ListBox's ItemsSource property to that ObservableCollection. Instead of only removing/adding items to database now, whenever I add/remove something from database, it is also changed in ObservableCollection. That way, UI is notified whenever something changes in database because those changes are reflected in ObservableCollection too.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't know whether you need a solution, but as per your last comment you're not satisfied... I'll illustrate my approach.

```
public class CustomersVm : INotifyPropertyChange
{ // just to point out, that you're using a VM class here   
   private ObservableCollection _customers;
   public ObservableCollection Customers
   { // since you're binding this to your listbox, DON'T change the reference during runtime
       get { return _customers ?? (_customers = new ObservableCollection());
   }

   // here comes your loading logic
   public void RefreshCustomers()
   {
       var customers = LoadCustomersFromDb(); // contains now a result set of model classes

       Customers.Clear(); //Clear the collection instead of creating it again.
       foreach(var customer in customers)
           Customers.Add(customer);
   }
}
```

Now the usage in XAML, which is working if the `DataContext` of the `Window` is set to the instance of `CustomersVm`. (Note: To be more general the `DataContext` of a parent element needs to be set like this.)

```
<Window DataContext=... >
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Customers} />
</Window>
```